# How to return more html templates in one script for python FLASK

Tags: python, html, function, flask, return

Hi i have an big python script and i want to pass an new html template after somethings happens. But it dont work for me. You can see my script under here i have placed tags with some text for the places i want to have it. i have used the return statement for the html but then it doesnt continue to the rest of the script. I hope someone can help me under here is my script i have placed in line 42 a tag with my problem

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/validate-user", methods=["POST"])
def validate_user():
 if request.method == "POST":
        name = (request.form['userid'])

        urlfix = ""

        for i in range(len(name)):
            if name[i] == ' ':
                urlfix = urlfix + '%20'
            else:
                urlfix = urlfix + name[i]

        MOurl = "https://dreate.monster/movies/search/?q=" + urlfix

        source = requests.get(MOurl).text

        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
        article1 = soup1.find('div', class_='image__placeholder')
        final2 = article1.find('img').get("data-src")
        print(final2)

        #here i want to return the html file i have with the variable "final2" but the problem im getting    is that if i use this piece of text: "return render_template("index.html", variable1=final2)" but if i use it up here the script stops running

        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
        article = soup.find('div', class_='mv-item-infor')
        final = article.find('a').get("href")

        final1 = "https://dreate.monster" + final

        page = requests.get(final1)
        bSoup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        links_list = bSoup.find('a', class_="round-button")
        final_link = links_list['href']

        old_url = final_link
        url = re.sub("sid=", "sid=2b5lj4nffh3lm9rfd4o2p7vv1j", old_url)
```